# How can I create an enumeration variable by groups?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, programming

I copied the title and concept for this question from [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/). I have

```
data = {{"ID", "Value"}, {1, 48}, {1, 45}, {1, 52}, {1, 43}, {1, 
    41}, {2, 50}, {2, 42}, {2, 51}, {2, 52}, {bb, 52}, {bb, 54}, {dd, 
    20}, {dd, 25}, {dd, 27}, {cc, 30}};
```

I want to create a new column called "Count" so that:

```
result = {{"ID", "Value", "Count"}, {1, 48, 1}, {1, 45, 2}, {1, 52, 
    3}, {1, 43, 4}, {1, 41, 5}, {2, 50, 1}, {2, 42, 2}, {2, 51, 
    3}, {2, 52, 4}, {bb, 52, 1}, {bb, 54, 2}, {dd, 20, 1}, {dd, 25, 
    2}, {dd, 27, 3}, {cc, 30, 1}};
```

I have a huge data with almost 2 billion observations. Therefore, efficient coding would save a lot of time and energy. As always, help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
r1 = Join[{Append[First[data], "Count"]}, Join @@ Values @ 
  GroupBy[Rest @data, First, MapIndexed[Join, #]&]]
```

> {{ID,Value,Count},{1,48,1},{1,45,2},{1,52,3},{1,43,4},{1,41,5},{2,50,1},{2,42,2},{2,51,3},{2,52,4},{bb,52,1},{bb,54,2},{dd,20,1},{dd,25,2},{dd,27,3},{cc,30,1}}

**Update 1:**

```
Prepend[Join @@ (MapIndexed[Join, #]&/@ SplitBy[Rest @ data, First]),
 Append[First[data], "Count"]]
```

> {{ID,Value,Count},{1,48,1},{1,45,2},{1,52,3},{1,43,4},{1,41,5},{2,50,1},{2,42,2},{2,51,3},{2,52,4},{bb,52,1},{bb,54,2},{dd,20,1},{dd,25,2},{dd,27,3},{cc,30,1}}

**Update 2:**

```
addCounter = Module[{cnt}, cnt[_String] := "Count"; cnt[_] := 1; {##, cnt[#]++} & @@@ #]&;

addCounter @ data
```

> {{"ID", "Value", "Count"}, {1, 48, 1}, {1, 45, 2}, {1, 52, 3}, {1, 43,
>          4}, {1, 41, 5}, {2, 50, 1}, {2, 42, 2}, {2, 51, 3}, {2, 52, 
>         4}, {bb, 52, 1}, {bb, 54, 2}, {dd, 20, 1}, {dd, 25, 2}, {dd, 27, 
>         3}, {cc, 30, 1}}

Comment: @ kglr, thank you for your answer. One of the problem of using gatherby (at least for me) is that it rearranges data based on id variable. Is there any way to keep the order of id variable the same. Thank you.

Comment: @ramesh, good point. I will post an update if i find a better solution.

Comment: @rames, please see the update.

Comment: I think it should work. I will apply it to my data and update you. Thank you so much kglr. You have helped me by answering most of my questions. I owe you more than I can pay!

Comment: @ramesh,  glad you found them useful.

Comment: @kglr How does your `cnt[#]++` work?

Comment: @Edmund, it is initialized to 1 for any possible value of its argument;  for every `x` ,  every time a sequence with `x` in the first slot is encountered, e,g, `Sequence[x, y_]`,  the current value of `cnt[x]` is appended to the sequence (to get  `{x, y cnt[x]}`) and `cnt[x]` is incremented.  ... Is this in any way an answer to your question?

Comment: @kglr Ah, I see. You are creating multiple *indexed* variables. The symbols/values precede the blank in the pattern match. Clever. I have not considered that.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one possibility using `Split` (which assumes that the IDs being counted always appear in runs)

```
splitcount = 
  Transpose[
    Flatten[{Transpose@#, 
      {Flatten[{
         "Count", Range /@ Length /@ Split[#[[2 ;;, 1]]]
      }]}
    }, 1]
  ] &;
```

To do some time trials on longer data lists (though not as long as the one you're looking at), first build some data:

```
SeedRandom[123]
idlist = Flatten[
   ConstantArray[#, RandomInteger[{1, 100}]] & /@ Range[10000]];
vallist = RandomInteger[{1, 60}, Length@idlist];
data = Join[{{"ID", "Value"}}, Transpose[{idlist, vallist}]];
Length@data

(* 507939 *)
```

Then

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res1 = splitcount[data];
 ]
AbsoluteTiming[
 (* @kglr *)
 res2 = Join[{Append[First[data], "Count"]}, 
    Join @@ Values@GroupBy[Rest@data, First, MapIndexed[Join, #] &]];
 ]
AbsoluteTiming[
 (* @kglr *)
 res3 = Prepend[
    Join @@ (MapIndexed[Join, #] & /@ SplitBy[Rest@data, First]), 
    Append[First[data], "Count"]];
 ]
AbsoluteTiming[
 (* @kglr *)
 res4 = addCounter@data;
 ]
AbsoluteTiming[
 (* @JasonB. *)
 keys = AssociationThread[Union[data[[2 ;;, 1]]] -> 0]; 
 tally = Join[{"Count"}, keys[#] += 1 & /@ data[[2 ;;, 1]]]; 
 res5 = MapThread[Append, {data, tally}];
 ]

res1 == res2 == res3 == res4 == res5

(* {0.416703, Null}
   {0.739995, Null}
   {1.16564, Null}
   {1.81539, Null}
   {1.93773, Null}
   True  *)
```

Comment: @ aardvark2012, thank you for answer. I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak to the efficiency of this, you'll have to try it on your dataset,

```
keys = AssociationThread[Union[data[[2 ;;, 1]]] -> 0];
tally = Join[{"Count"}, keys[#] += 1 & /@ data[[2 ;;, 1]]];
data2 = MapThread[Append, {data, tally}]

(* {{"ID", "Value", "Count"}, {1, 48, 1}, {1, 45, 2}, {1, 52, 
  3}, {1, 43, 4}, {1, 41, 5}, {2, 50, 1}, {2, 42, 2}, {2, 51, 3}, {2, 
  52, 4}, {bb, 52, 1}, {bb, 54, 2}, {dd, 20, 1}, {dd, 25, 2}, {dd, 27,
   3}, {cc, 30, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Jason. I really appreciate it for its simplicity.